# Ignore directory

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to ignore a directory when i do a diff against the master branch

```
changed=()
while IFS='' read -r line; do changed+=("$line"); done < <(git --no-pager diff --':!modules*' origin/master --name-only | sed 's#\(.*\)/.*#\1#' | uniq)
echo "Files changed: ${changed[*]}"
```

folder structure: I want to ignore any modules/* directory.

```
script.sh 
dev-1
  - nonprod 
      - dir1
      - dir2
  - prod
      - testdir1
      - testdir2
dev-2
  - modules
     - content-dir
  - nonprod
     - content-dir
  - prod
```

Answer (score 1):

You've gone way overboard writing this bash script, trying to compensate for what's really just a typo:

> ```
> git --no-pager diff --':!modules*'
> ```

This needs to be:

```
git --no-pager diff -- ':!modules*'
```

Note the single <kbd>SPACE</kbd> between the two dashes and the `':!modules*'` pathspec.

(If you want to ignore `modules` and all its subdirectories, `:!modules` is sufficient.  The `*` at the end will have Git skip over files or directories named, e.g., `modulesfrink` and `moduleszoidberg` as well as `modules`, so it's probably harmless.)

Separately, the *branch* argument to `git diff`, as well as the `--name-only` part, must come *before* the `--`, so you actually need:

```
git --no-pager diff origin/master --name-only -- ':!modules'
```

The `--`, surrounded by spaces on both sides, tells Git: *everything after this is a pathspec*.  While `:!modules` *is* a pathspec, `origin/master` and `--name-only` are *not* pathspecs.